Animator animates his two little girls talking and role playing
Since the 1970s ( or possibly 90s ?? ) I have been remembering and wondering how I could ever again find this gem.  I believe it is Canadian, possibly National Film Board.  I think it's about 15 minutes long.
The animator/film maker took his family to a lake house.  He sat with his two 4 & 6 yr old daughters on the dock drawing and listening to their conversation.  He became so fascinated by their intertwined monologues, dialogs and stream of consciousness role playing that he turned on a tape-recorder in order to later share it with family and friends. The girls rambled through talk of fish and frogs, ships in the clouds, fairies becoming dragonflies if anyone looks at them, ogres from the story they'd had read to them the night before.
At some point the animator was inspired to animate the narrative, and thus the film was made.  I remember the drawing style was appealing and the flow from scene to scene was smooth and elegant. Can't remember if it was colored, but think not.
You can imagine how sad I am to have no idea how to find it.

Sounds a lot like the Hubleys' short animations of their children's conversations and particularly Windy Day from 1967, but the conversation there is a little different.
In 1959, animators John and Faith Hubley recorded their two small boys having a conversation about a moonbird and animated it; the short went on to win an Oscar. They followed up Moonbird with Windy Day (1967) and Cockaboody (1973), this time animating the conversations between their two small daughters, Georgia and Emily.
The closest to your description is Windy Day, in which Georgia and Emily discuss a play based on a fairy tale that invloves a dragon; it was nominated for an Oscar. It's possible you're looking for some other Hubleys short, but these are the ones I know of that feature their children. Here it is:




Thank you so much.  You are probably right that Windy Day is the one I saw.    It was during a children's short film festival, so I must've pulled in memories from some of the other films.  I've also tried to describe it to friends over the years and have been remembering my own embellishments.  It's sad how fragile our memories are.
